# Is it possible to archive and distribute an iOS app without an iphone device?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I have a Mac Mini and Xcode and the app is running in the simulator. I also have a paying Apple Developer account. I cannot find informaiton if having an actual iphone is mandatory or not.

Comment: You really should test your app on a real device; The simulator is good, but it is not perfect.  You need at least one real device registered in your developer account in order to generate the profiles required to archive your product, but this can be a phone you borrow or connect for just the time taken to register it.

Comment: You can try inviting people with TestFlight

Comment: @Paulw11 a phone I borrow cannot do if it's logged in with the apple account of my friend correct? Or it doesn't matter?

Comment: @PtitXav from my understanding I cannot archive it for TestFlight if I don't have a real phone. Do you know of a way to do it without?

Comment: It doesn't matter about the apple account on the phone. You just need to load the udid into your developer account. In theory your friend can just send you the value and you can enter it at developer.apple.com but it is easier to connect the phone to your Mac and build your app to it, which will register the device. From that time on you are good.